# Upgrading to PHP 5.6 on OSX

Tags: php, macos

Im trying to run a command:

```
 sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Output:

```
Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements
```

Then i did:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

That seemed to work.

So i tried to run the command again.

Same error.

Then i did php -v

Output:

```
PHP 5.5.24 (cli) (built: May 19 2015 10:10:05) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Then i tried installing again using:

curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6\

Output:

Already installed.

Im using osx yosemite

Comment: Check if it's installed in /usr/local/bin. Could be your /usr/bin is before your local bin in your path.

Comment: in usr/local there are 2 versions the old one and the newer one @M.Alnashmi How to continue from here?

Comment: In terminal, export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin, then do: which php.

Comment: Did that now @M.Alnashmi

Comment: Got this @M.Alnashmi /usr/bin/php after running which php

Comment: Then the export didn't work, where is the php in your /usr/local located?

Comment: in usr/local there are 2 different php versions one named  php5   and one  php5-5.6.25-20160831-101628 @M.Alnashmi

Comment: export path=/usr/local/php5-5.625-20160831-101628/bin

Comment: did which php and got this /usr/bin/php

Comment: @M.Alnashmi After doing what you said

Comment: I'm just trying to figure where php was installed. Do an ls -l to the php directory in /usr/local/php5-5.625-201608031-101628

Comment: @M.Alnashmi export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH; did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing php like this `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6` I had to run `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH;` then it worked.